# base operand of '->' has non-pointer value; but I'm almost certain it has pointer type?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have defined a struct named wire:

```
typedef struct wire
{
    char type[9];
    char name[20];
    char value;
    struct io * inp=NULL;
    struct io * outp=NULL;
} wire;
```

and another named io:

```
typedef struct io
{
    struct io* next;
    struct log_gate* conn_gate ;
} io;
```

wires is a dynamic array of wire.

and compile error occurs in this line:

```
tmp=&wires[i]->outp;
```

The compile error is: base operand of '->' has non-pointer value 'wire'

Comment: When it comes right down to it, to the part where the error happens (`tmp` and `wires`), you stopped showing us actual code. Is there any particular reason for that?

Comment: I realized that it's not visible what type is `tmp` and how you declared `wires` so it's not a good answer I gave, and I deleted it. Please post at least the part where you declare `tmp` and `wires`.

Comment: You might be almost certain that `wires[i]` has pointer type, but how can we be sure if you don't show us the declaration of `wires`?

Answer (score 2):

First we must take a look at the precedence of both operators in question. According to [this chart](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), `->` has a higher precedence than `&`. This means that we must evaluate the `->` before the `&`. Lets take a look at the expression.

```
wires[i] /// this returns a wire
```

Due to the precedence of `->` we now evaluate the struct accessor operation.

```
wires[i]->outp /// because wires[i] is a wire, not a wire *, the -> is misused.
```

`wires[i]` is just a plain old `wire`, not a pointer, so we must use the `.` operator to access its members. Remember, `->` vs `.` is determined by the type of the *struct*, not the type of the *member*. Because the *struct* is not a pointer, we use `.`

The precedence issue is important because if `&` had a higher precendence than `->`, then the expression `&wires[i]` would be evaluated first. This would mean that we are trying to get at the `outp` field of a `wire *` instead of a `wire`, and the `->` operator would be justified.

Comment: Don't conflate precedence with evaluation order.

Answer (score 2):

Write either

```
tmp = ( &wires[i] )->outp;
```

or

```
tmp = wires[i].outp;
```

If `wires` is a pointer to allocated memory of an array then `wires[i]` is an element of the array and has type `struct wire` that is it is not a pointer. So the correct syntax will be as the second example of statement shown above.

If you uses the address of this element like `&wires[i]` then unary operator `&` has lower priority than postfix operator `->`. So you need to enclose expression `&wires[i]` in parentheses `(&wires[i])` like it is shown in the first example of statement above that to get a pointer.